# IOption pattern - unit testing and passing through layers

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, repository-pattern

I have some code (C# .Net Core WebAPI) I wish to unit test but need some help as the dependencies looks a bit odd to me.

The code came from some sample code (I found on the web) for accessing MongoDb using .Net Core WebAPI, which initially looked ok, until now..

Both the DbContext and the Repository have the same dependency - and the Repository just passes it through to the DbContext anyway - as the Repository instantiates the DbContext:

```
  public class LogItemRepository : ILogItemRepository
  {
    private readonly DbContext _context = null;

    public LogItemRepository(IOptions<DbSettings> settings)
    {
      _context = new DbContext(settings);
    }
```

...

```
  public class DbContext
  {
    private readonly IMongoDatabase _database = null;

    public DbContext(IOptions<DbSettings> settings)
    {
      var client = new MongoClient(settings.Value.ConnectionString);
      if (client != null)
        _database = client.GetDatabase(settings.Value.Database);
    }

    public IMongoCollection<LogItem> LogItemsCollection
    {
      get
      {
        return _database.GetCollection<LogItem>("LogItem");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not familiar with the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#options-config-objects), but from a quick read it looks good.  But I'm not convinced it's good practice to make child dependencies (the options), dependencies of the parent (as in the example above).

Instead should I be making an interface, IDbContext, and using that as the dependency for the repository?   That's what I would have done in the past - but not sure if this breaks the options pattern.

I suspect this is subjective, but I'd like some others input.

Thanks
Tim

Comment: While primarily opinion based, common practice is to not instantiate the db context within the constructor of the repository. That tightly couples the repository to the context. Inject an abstraction as you stated in your OP. Only the context seems to rely on the options abstraction

Comment: +1 on Nkosi's comment. Having the repository instantiate a context will lead to all kinds of problems down the road. 5 repositories would be potentially using 5 contexts meaning references to entities passed around/returned will be left out of scope of their context or a bunch of messy wiring to detach/reattach entities between contexts. As far as unit tests go (as in TDD/BDD tests) cut your mocking off at the Repository level, as in mock the repository rather than trying to mock at the context level. Integration tests with a db can test the repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While primarily opinion based, common practice is to not instantiate the db context within the constructor of the repository. That tightly couples the repository to the context. Inject an abstraction as you stated in your OP.

I may be splitting hairs here but there is still too much tight coupling in the example provided.

First abstract the context

```
public interface IDbContext {
    IMongoCollection<LogItem> LogItemsCollection { get; }
}
```

and also have `IMongoDatabase` be an explicit dependency

```
public class DbContext : IDbContext {
    private readonly IMongoDatabase database = null;

    public DbContext(IMongoDatabase database) 
        this.database = database;
    }

    public IMongoCollection<LogItem> LogItemsCollection {
        get {
            return database.GetCollection<LogItem>("LogItem");
        }
    }
}
```

configure service with what ever options are needed at the composition root (Startup). You would even consider encapsulating it in an extension method.

```
services.AddScoped<IMongoDatabase>(provider => {
    var settings = provider.GetService<IOptions<DbSettings>>();
    var client = new MongoClient(settings.Value.ConnectionString);
    return client.GetDatabase(settings.Value.Database);
});
services.AddScoped<IDbContext, DbContext>();
services.AddScoped<ILogItemRepository, LogItemRepository>();
//...NOTE: Use the desired service lifetime. This is just an example
```

That now leaves the repository to be explicitly dependent on the context abstraction

```
public class LogItemRepository : ILogItemRepository {
    private readonly IDbContext context = null;

    public LogItemRepository(IDbContext context) {
         this.context = context;
    }

    //...other code
}
```

All layers are now decoupled and explicitly state what their dependencies are, allowing for more isolated unit tests to be done as needed.

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi - that looks better to me. Will go with that approach.